# How to add new method in aspxclienttextbox?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, custom-server-controls

Can I add new method to aspxclienttextbox control?
I'm doing custom control on the aspxtextbox...
I wish to add client-side method on the custom control and i have no idea on it...
So anyone know how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of two methods to achieve this:

1.Add method to object prototype:

```
ASPxClientTextBox.prototype.NewMethod = function(param1) { console.log(param1); }
```

According to [this ticket](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q133745.aspx) you should place this code at the end of body section.

2.Use `ASPxTextBox` [ClientSideEvents.Init](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientControl_Inittopic) in your custom control code. This will dinamically register method for every `ASPxTextBox` instance (while first method modifies object prototype).

```
ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e) {s.NewMethod = function(param1) { console.log(param1); }}";
```

Comment: After that i able to use ASPxClientTextBox1(client instance name).NewMethod(param1); ?

Comment: what i want is add a new method to the ASPxClientTextBox so that every time i can call that method on client side and i also don't want to add extra code on the page

Comment: Both methods will do what you want.

Comment: Sir, but if i have 2 same control in a page, the function script will write on page 2 times i may have many custom controls on a single page in this case the traffic maybe an issue when web browser request to web server.....

Comment: You can use first approach then, or declare function body in js file and call that function using one of suggested mwthods.